# Compare list of dicts with pandas series and populate dict based on match

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a list of dicts that I want to populate by updating the dict if a match of several values within a dict is found in a pandas series. e.g

```
lis_of_dicts = [{'A':'a', 'B':'b','C':'c', 'D':'d'},
                {'A':'1', 'B':'2','C':'3','D':'4'}, 
                {'A':'M','B':'N','C':'O','D':'P'}]

dd = {'col1':['b', 'M'], 'col2':['d','P'], 'col3':['7.5','29']}
df = pd.Dataframe(dd, columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']) 
pd_series = pd.Series(tuple(value) for value in df.values), index=df.index)
```

which generated:

```
0 (b, d, 7.5)
1 (M, P, 29)
```

Desired result:

```
[{'A':'a', 'B':'b','C':'c', 'val': '7.5','D':'d'}, 
 {'A':'1', 'B':'2','C':'3', 'val':'NA', 'D':'4'}, 
 {'A':'M','B':'N','C':'O','val':'29','D':'P'}]
```

I tried this but I could not even get the match so could not proceed:

```
for i in pd_series:
    for x in lis_of_dicts:
        if [x[key] == i[0] in x and [x[key] == i[1] in x for key in x]:
            x.update({'val':'i[2]'})
        else:
            x.update({'val':'NA'})
```

I am unable to generate any result. Notice the order of the dict should remain the same except for the value been added should be before the last item in the dictionary.

Comment: I want a list of updated dictionaries as output

Comment: val is just any string you want to name it but the value is picked based on the 3rd column in the pandas series

Comment: What is df here?

Comment: df is the dataframe that contains the values you see in the pd series

Comment: @Starter That's not what cs95 meant. In simple words, please add df to the question. You can [edit] from here.

Comment: I added  the dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for a nested loop based solution:

```
>>> df_2 = pd.DataFrame(lis_of_dicts)
>>> df_2
   A  B  C  D
0  a  b  c  d
1  1  2  3  4
2  M  N  O  P
>>> cols = df_2.columns
>>> for ix, row in df_2.iterrows():
...     for item in pd_series:
...         if set(row[cols]) & set(item):
...             df_2.loc[ix, 'val'] = item[2]
...             break
...     else:
...         df_2.loc[ix, 'val'] = 'NA'

>>> df_2.to_dict('r')
[{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'c', 'D': 'd', 'val': 7.5},
 {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3', 'D': '4', 'val': 'NA'},
 {'A': 'M', 'B': 'N', 'C': 'O', 'D': 'P', 'val': 29}]
```

**EDIT**:
It can be simplified, as follows:

```
output = []
for d in lis_of_dicts:
    for item in pd_series:
        if set(d.values()) & set(item):
            d['val'] = item[2]
            break
    else:
        d['val'] = 'NA'
    output.append(d)
>>> output
[{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'c', 'D': 'd', 'val': 7.5},
 {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3', 'D': '4', 'val': 'NA'},
 {'A': 'M', 'B': 'N', 'C': 'O', 'D': 'P', 'val': 29}]
```

**EDIT 2**:

**NOTE:** This will only reliably work in python version >= 3.7, as order is not guaranteed to be maintained in `dict`s for lower versions.

To place `val` in 2nd last element:

```
output = []
for d in lis_of_dicts:
    last = d.popitem()
    for item in pd_series:
        if set(d.values()) & set(item):
            d['val'] = item[2]
            d.update([last])
            break
    else:
        d['val'] = 'NA'
        d.update([last])
    output.append(d)

>>> output
[{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', 'C': 'c', 'val': 7.5, 'D': 'd'},
 {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3', 'val': 'NA', 'D': '4'},
 {'A': 'M', 'B': 'N', 'C': 'O', 'val': 29, 'D': 'P'}]
```

Comment: This does not solve it for me though and I updated the desired result

Comment: @Starter Hi there, if you are running into issues getting this solution to work for you, it would be extremely helpful to explain why. We need to understand what you are seeing that we aren't. We want to help you, but you have to enable us to do that. Cheers :-)

Comment: I provided all the info I have. I am not sure what else will help. If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: That's fine. Can you let us know what issue are you facing while trying this solution?

Comment: The added value is not getting populated. Its a large file and probably the set may not work given that the value to match may be in different dictionaries that are far apart within the list of dicts

Comment: I don't see why that should be the case, as I did the all the steps on the data you provided. However, added a simpler version, see if it helps.

Comment: it does help me understand it. I think it works now. I am trying to learn as much so the simpler version helped me understood the first one. Is it possible to append 'val' to the second to last element in each dict?